# What happens when we multiply a scalar with matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following two matrices.

A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 4 \\ 5 & 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 6 & -7 \end{bmatrix}
B = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 2 \\ -6 & 4 & 1 \\ 7 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}

Show the following hold (assuming $c \in \mathbb{R})$.

**(d)** $c(AB) = (cA)B \quad$   **(e)** $A(cB) = (Ac)B \quad$ **(f)** $(AB)c = A(Bc)$

I don't understand what $c$ represents in this problem. Can you show me how to do one of these?

Comment: $cA$ and $Ac$ probably both mean multiplying each of the elements of $A$ by $c$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The question refers to $c$ but not $C$.  To multiply a matrix by a real number (scalar), multiply each component of the matrix by the real number

Comment: $c$ is  simply a scalar.  $c\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 4 \\ 5 & 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 6 & -7 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} c\cdot2 & c\cdot0 & c\cdot4 \\ c\cdot5 & c\cdot1 & c\cdot-2 \\ c\cdot1 & c\cdot6 & c\cdot-7 \end{bmatrix}$.  The question is saying to show if you muliply two matrixes together and then multiplied by a scalar on the left it'll have the same result as multiplying one matrix by the scalar and then multiplying the resulting matrix by the second and so on.... in other words, it doesn't matter when you multiply by the scalar the result will be the same.

Comment: The notation is really bad. Why Have a scalar named c and a matrix named C, especially when the matrix C is not involved at all?

Comment: You right, I deleted C matrix.

Comment: Please don’t repost your [closed questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3647576/265466) virtually verbatim after they’ve been closed for not having enough context. You should make some effort to improve the question; deleting one of the matrices didn’t do that. You’re fortunate that someone answered it instead of this second attempt also simply being closed. Next time you might not be that lucky. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for ways to improve your questions and prevent them from being closed outright.

Answer (score 1):

c is just a real number, and when you multiply c and a matrix, you multiply each of the matrix entries by c. For your matrix A:
$$c*\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 4 \\ 5 & 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 6 & -7 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2c & 0 & 4c \\ 5c & c & -2c \\ c & 6c & -7c \end{bmatrix}$$